# function to get the highest common divisor between two numbers

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a function to get the highest common divisor between two numbers, but I am getting an error `Ambiguous variable occurrence "gcd"`.

```
gcd a 0 = 0
gcd 0 a = 0
gcd a b = if a > b
    then (if mod a b == 0 then a else gcd a (b-1))
    else (if mod b a == 0 then b else gcd (a-1) b)
```

How it will be executed:
1- find the greatest of two numbers
2- then the greatest mod smallest; if it equals zero then it will return the smallest, otherwise
it will call method again but with (smallest - 1) and the same value for the greatest

Comment: that's because the `Prelude` already has a `gcd`, so name your function `gcd'` for example.

Comment: If you rename the function, make sure you rename all uses of it. You don’t want to accidentally use the Prelude `gcd` instead of a recursive call

Comment: This algorithm is probably correct, but it is very, very slow. You might want to read about other gcd algorithms a bit once you get this working.

Comment: I don't think the algorithm is even correct - just running through it in my head with `gcd 8 6` comes out as 4 when 4 does not divide 6. (Actually no, it will give 8, because you return the wrong number when one divides the other...)

Comment: The algorithm needs to be checked. e.g. for gcd of 10 and 6, it is finding gcd of 10 and 5. That's not correct.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)